# Orbeon Single sign-on to SAP Netweaver

Tags: security, single-sign-on, orbeon, sap-basis, netweaver

We have setup Orbeon 4.0 beta 3 on SAP Netweaver 7.3 with custom persistancy layer.

This layer is created on Netweaver with this in mind: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api
Basic CXF webservices which acts as a proxy to the SAP Backend where we store the form and data. Connection to the backend is made via SAP HTTPDestination.

This setup works as long as authentication is turn off in web.xml etc.

The next step was to enable this with SSO in mind. So that the persistancy layer is called with the same SSO ticket to enable usercontext passing to the SAP backend.

Steps:

1. Enable security in orbeon web.xml and web-j2ee-engine with proper SAP role and login stack (ticket)
2. Enable security on the persistency layer
3. Setup orbeon to pass the MYSAPSSO2 cookie (property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.http.forward-cookies" value="MYSAPSSO2"/>)

Looking at the browser window I see the JSESSIONID and MYSAPSSO2 cookies.  This is supported by java filter I made in front of Orbeon to read the cookies. 
This filter in front of the Orbeon loops over the Cookie[] array of the Servlet request.

I have 3 log records of this and what caught my eye was that the JSESSION of the first log record looked like this

```
Cookie: JSESSIONID   0iqTevo1vDb_lYFwTa-9CJHymaGMPAHaCk0A_SAPox1Z6aY-RvYBtiK-2U5GLmAh
```

the following records did look like this:

```
Cookie: JSESSIONID   0iqTevo1vDb_lYFwTa-9CJHymaGMPAHaCk0A_SAP
```

So first question is why the trim of the JSESSIONID?

Looking at the logs of the percistancy layer this class shows an error:

```
com.sap.engine.services.security.authentication.loginmodule.ticket
Base64 Encoded Ticket String: 0iqTevo1vDb_lYFwTa-9CJHymaGMPAHaCk0A_SAP
```

It looks to me that SAP can handle this shorter JSESSIONID.

A test via browser:

1. Open Orbeon forms url
2. Log into SAP by the login page shown
3. Open the `/rest/test` (url of the persistancy layer) to see if I have to login again

No login required when opening `/rest/test` and no errors in the login regarding  `com.sap.engine.services.security.authentication.loginmodule.ticket`

Comment: I don't remember having seen a "truncated" cookie like this ever before. Intriguing. At which point do you see those two different cookies, and where do you observe them? Is it on the browser in both cases?

Comment: The first one is from the filter I placed in front of the orbeon main servlet.
The 2nd in frot of Jersey servlet which handels the crud calls from orbeon.

Comment: Got it. Then as mentioned on the mailing list, I will try to reproduce this using Tomcat; I will let you know what I find.